# Dynamic querySelector with Dynamic Jinja HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, jinja2

I have forms that are rendered dynamically based on values in a dictionary. They are given an ID based on the key value. They are all initially hidden.

```
<div id="subforms" style="display: none" >
  {%for k, v in options.items() %}
    <h3>{{k}}:</h3> 
    <form id= "{{k}}">
    {% for option in v %}
      <label>{{option}}</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="{{option}}_enabled">
    {% endfor %}
    </form>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I now create an input list with those same keys:

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input list="tables" id="tablelist" >
    <datalist id="tables">
    {% for key in options.keys() %}
      <option value={{key}}>
    {% endfor %}
    </datalist>
</form>
```

Last I have Javascript used to listen to the tablelist element and select a form based on the inputlist's value.

```
const tables = document.getElementById("tablelist")
const subform_block = document.getElementById("subform_display")
const forms = document.getElementById("subforms")

tables.oninput = () => {
  let form = 
  forms.querySelector('form[id="${tables.value}"]');

if(form){
    subform_block.innerHTML = form.outerHTML;
} 
else {
    subform_block.innerHTML = "not found";
}
 }
```

The querySelector is not working. I confirmed that the HTML is rendered correctly and the IDs are consistent, but my querySelector is unable to find any of the forms. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed:

```
let form = forms.querySelector('form[id="${tables.value}"]');
```

to:

```
document.querySelector('form[id=' + tables.value + ']');
```

And it works. Not sure why ${tables.value} wasn't recognized properly

Comment: JQuery uses " ` " and not " ' "

{{facepalm}}